# Date label doesn't show on the Canvasjs chart when using JSON data

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to use Canvasjs to draw a graph representing blood test results.
My JSON data appears to be fine, and when I run it it creates the graph with the `y` values only. Nothing on the `x`.

Here is my JSON data:

```
[
    {
        "legend": "t3",
        "x": "2004-07-05",
        "y": 6.8
    },
    {
        "legend": "t4",
        "x": "2004-07-05",
        "y": 29
    },
    {
        "legend": "tsh",
        "x": "2004-07-05",
        "y": 0.01
    },
    {
        "legend": "thyroglobulin level",
        "x": "2004-07-05",
        "y": 0.5
    },
    {
        "legend": "t3",
        "x": "2005-06-15",
        "y": 5.2
    },
    {
        "legend": "t4",
        "x": "2005-06-15",
        "y": 30
    },
    {
        "legend": "tsh",
        "x": "2005-06-15",
        "y": 0.02
    },
    {
        "legend": "thyroglobulin level",
        "x": "2005-06-15",
        "y": 0.5
    }
]
```

Here is my page code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

        $("#find").click(function(e){

            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                // the URL for the request
                url: "bloodTest.php",
                // the data to send (will be converted to a query string)
                data: {pnhsno: "1001001002"},
                // whether this is a POST or GET request
                type: "GET",
                // the type of data we expect back
                dataType : "json",
                // code to run if the request succeeds;
                // the response is passed to the function
                success: function(json){

                    $("#chart").CanvasJSChart({ //Pass chart options
                         title:{text:"Blood Test Results"},
                         //axisX:{valueFormatString:"DD-MM-YYYY",labelAngle:-45},
                        data: [{
                        type: "line", //change it to column, spline, line, pie, etc
                        xValueType:"date",
                        dataPoints:json}]
                    });
                //chart.render();
                }

            }); 
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert values on your x-axis to javascript `Date` objects like this:

```
[
  {
    "legend": "t3",
    "x": new Date(2004, 7, 5),
    "y": 6.8
  },
  {
    "legend": "t4",
    "x": new Date(2004, 7, 5),
    "y": 29
  },
  {
    "legend": "tsh",
    "x": new Date(2004, 7, 5),
    "y": 0.01
  },
  .....
];
```

More examples can be found [here](http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/date-time-axis/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to transform your `x` data points to `Date` before passing them to the chart:

```
// To use the jQuery version
//var dataPoints = $.map(data, function (p) {
var dataPoints = json.map(function (p) {
    p.x = new Date(p.x);
    return p;
});
$("#chart").CanvasJSChart({ //Pass chart options
    title:{text:"Blood Test Results"},
    //axisX:{valueFormatString:"DD-MM-YYYY",labelAngle:-45},
    data: [{
      type: "line", //change it to column, spline, line, pie, etc
      //xValueType:"date",
      dataPoints: dataPoints
    }]
});
```

Comment: the only thing that I was expecting four lines of each to represent one type of blood test on the chart.  like T3, T4, TSH and which they were called legends in My JSON data..  Many Many thanks